# Picking correct enum type to access object nested property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, typescript-typings, object-properties

It is quite common case for me but yet I didn't stumble upon easy solution for this.

I have following enums (there are more values for each enum but for sake of simplicity I trimmed them down to two. Also note that same enum keys and values in every one of them is just a result of trimming and is not the specific case):

```js
enum CampPersons {
    HEALER = 'healer',
    MERCHANT = 'merchant',
    TUTOR = 'tutor',
}
enum HealerUpgrades {
    UNLOCK = 'unlock',
    TRAVEL = 'travel',
}

enum MerchantUpgrades {
    UNLOCK = 'unlock',
    TRAVEL = 'travel',
}

enum TutorUpgrades {
    UNLOCK = 'unlock',
}

export type CampPersonUpgrades = HealerUpgrades | MerchantUpgrades | TutorUpgrades;
```

then I have object using those enums like this:

```js
export const CampPersonUpgradesIcons = {
    [CampPersons.HEALER]: {
        [HealerUpgrades.UNLOCK]: HealIcon,
        [HealerUpgrades.TRAVEL]: TravelIcon,
    },
    [CampPersons.MERCHANT]: {
        [MerchantUpgrades.UNLOCK]: GoldIcon,
        [MerchantUpgrades.TRAVEL]: TravelIcon,
    },
    [CampPersons.TUTOR]: {
        [TutorUpgrades.UNLOCK]: BookIcon,
    },
};
```

The problem arises when I try to access appropriate icon for person upgrade

```js
const person: CampPersons = ...;
const upgrade: CampPersonUpgrades = ...;

const icon = CampPersonUpgradesIcons[person][upgrade];
```

Obviously typescript compiler can't determine if `upgrade` used to access specific icon is correct for `CampPersonUpgradesIcons[person]` because it can be either `HealerUpgrades`, `MerchantUpgrades` or `TutorUpgrades`.

Obviously for human (not typescript) when `person` is `CampPersons.HEALER` then `upgrade` would be from `HealerUpgrades`. My question is what is the easiest way to tell typescript compiler that `upgrade` for `person` will match appropriate enum (without using conditional typing like `upgrade extends HealerUpgrades ? HealerUpgrades : ...` or `//@ts-ignore` ).

**Edit:** I used @jcalz answer in my React component but unfortunately I've encountered further problems illustrated in [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghhADgBWAJwM4HsQagbwFgAoKKACQFEBBAGUoCUoBeKAcgAtg4AbdNgDQkyAWUYxy1AHIAVFuwjoAxhzggALoOFQZAVRkB5Jqzbqw6rGi3EAviVCQK3Pml2IA5mjgATYHiKkULpStAYwANLybGAgPFhKANbWZDIM1ABqlLRR6l4AbsA81nbE9uDQIsqqGm6ePn4E2sGhEVExcYnJOmmZ2Sa5cAVFQrYkZY4y5pa1Xr7+TSFhkSbt8UkjJSTqAJ6IwLAIKOjYIDP1eKzkzuhnc1AAPlCVaCpq6rcNj5MWrh6zfgBuMbEACWGnQADM4Ep9gBJJQ4RqBOZKNAgxDqEE4ABcUAwuTB7iBo1KxARuHUTl48JxUBpIHk+CgKLRGKxIFxACIqHQAIScqA2Ynk-E6fKFem4+mM5l+VHozG0zmpDJZfmC4U4UUAcSwPG8krp5JlLIV7K52oMtAAIuqhSQRZSAEJYLAJQ3S1hM01spVOgwGcJ24HAAAeiEslMdByQqEwOA+GHpFyRZAA2vBY8ctQA6Hn0BgAXVxATI6auvBuf3OOeaS2LVJ49JGZagaYrLkTOZVvQbMnFTfJLcFw4zhzjJwwObEDAk0hkDdLZbTz1eNWrc1riwiDd1+ub2nTq+q7w3fm7PSyfYHB8CNlHmaO8dw3f0RkXh7b32mZ6ndZ3uIum6t5kPeJD2qSEIxEoioMu4wDqPSAA8yBQGG6igN4eCPhOWoAHwABTaHsz64sgAhQGAZ64gkwDbFgEJQDsewMTGT4nImyZpsghYAJSplAaAIWAaAMjh2anL+XEkSchZplRdS+IWAJQAA9KpUBunA2zgcC0ZcJWrixGsnpQPBiHkgR4nPlO+aMBRHZVop57-uEvEqepmkJNpDpapSrqIEmxqsOZ9JWeOElTjOc6yBR36-M5f7bm5HkaegaCWLyJCeQAtHl+UFYVRXFSVRV4VAAB+VXVTVtW1dlGlsPFiZsFAIJ4CAWCUnAGAYCC7ggHAABGfBMVg7DHm8LXAg1UClfNC2LUty15bNUjAAA7lA5IYRozJYBtDJcEJs0rWd50XYVel+cy2yDRAIJKLhHJsc9KbWZOr6GAwmoUrd92PR8uIfQmv7yM1v5bi04TEp5VxCW1xrtW1DJQjBmmMcxcLkr5f2PYiIUIWF3h3Qgj3PRRJMA0oHzucCuWXYzTPzcCYIYWgaP7B8yAZYFAlkDJtIg7gw5kAp-zAxFz6JsOmzEFBIAweyQRngRS6CyAw7i-U4G4tzvMYPxS5kJ5+MMhgHBYGA+pQEN+ysVjRo4BRQ3mCj+LcN4bWUsjIDAAUaCftGZvyKFlkaxR2u+HTgRkEJZiiVA4A8DwxJywzzOZ1nrPghz0Jc2ePNYIF2qgOgj0oRJaGhrtWGvZF5XG1AGtkRJouUdRUC0fRmO7MArHC5xIrcRJhay8CCtK4iHyl37aJKJXz7V7X2FS5OhHq232hR8Ausq85Rcl2X8+LyceFG9ocPoPsIfI0J2A8AUXsImgQkwTw2y227ShvLb+yDa-A6wAvYWCdgyLG2hg7kilMFeu0spLDw1nJHeyldKkgzlnTBl0c7s05nAjiv4RBwEQAJMcWYbJ5hoAWBsjkEr-AwA+NeuZoqSFkA2Sa65EqMPIZ9PQ30+xTDoecDYODIT533v8Q+GBZ7lyUEQxAp9EToUwqvHh+F+bNwkq3Z87cd6SzUZJRK8iR7PjHtoOWk9YISPqDI+e8jFEMmUSAOuwsMAb2IlvQIO89762LtI4+j17HPXPgJK+CMd7bTUJ1SkdtKIYGAWNFGvhQz4NBolaSo9IE3TNjAgmqTDH0IyaY+SZ5UG2CAA)

Answer (score 0):

As you note, you can't just say that `person` is of type `CampPersons` and that  `upgrade` is of type `CampPersonUpgrades` and expect the compiler to understand how they are related.  It's possible you might want the icon-indexing code to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the type of `person`, like this:

```
function getIcon<P extends CampPersons>(
  person: P, upgrade: keyof typeof CampPersonUpgradesIcons[P]) {
  return CampPersonUpgradesIcons[person][upgrade]; // okay
}
```

Here `person` is now of generic type `P` which is constrained to `CampPersons`, and the type of `upgrade` is explicitly related to `P`.  This gives you the following behavior:

```
const healerUnlockIcon = getIcon(CampPersons.HEALER, HealerUpgrades.UNLOCK); // okay
const oopsIcon = getIcon(CampPersons.MERCHANT, TutorUpgrades.UNLOCK); // error!
// ------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// 'TutorUpgrades' is not assignable to 'MerchantUpgrades'
```

Does that meet your needs or at least give you some direction?  Good luck!

[Playground Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-F6ab14zJ8Yn-smMSXXRaPdaMF6xAwJNIZPHgyHnZU0Co1Ooo9nYxF46z2UntKG2x2apm7Tmell84Wh4EbGW3ZbPbgc-ojE3h6nJhYM3Vo73wvG5Qr52RFz8sSQ9jElJSVe5gOpCQAeZBQQ3qUDePDLys4gAfAAFNoiBWqCyACFAYATr4LwJMAACeWB7FA6hIeBqHmu6EE2nBfgOs6yD+gAlJcZBoM+YBoCq-54d29pMs64Grv6zqwQewD+p8UAAPR8VACpwEhPx6maXC8JGsRrNyrBPi+-zAfRq7Vr6jDQeGUn7lm1ZHqRvECUJCQiVKOKAvKiBMSSUAKYSykVnh1a1vWsjQbu0wEXpiwRAZ-GCegaCWCiJBGQAtBFkVRdFMWxXFMWAVAAB+KWpWl6XpaFglsB5Ol2mwUBbHgIBYICcAYBgWzuCAcAAEZ8OhWDsKO1Rdl5bB6p1pTdSQQA)

Comment: Hey, your solution works well and is pretty clean but unfortunately I couldn't manage to implement it in my React component (see edit in original post)

Comment: In each case the compiler is unable to understand the relationship between `person` and `upgrade`.  In `dynamicPerson` and `dynamicUpgrade` the compiler knows the actual value because [initializing a variable of union type will narrow by control-flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513).  In your other code it does not.  To get the desired behavior you will need to use the same or sufficiently similar generic signature as `getIcon()`, with `P extends CampPersons`, and `keyof typeof CampPersonUpgradesIcons[P]`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried that solution and as a result it gives another error (line 93 in playground I've linked). This time for some reason result of `CampPersonUpgradesIcons[person][upgrade]` is not treated as `Icon`. Any idea how to overcome it?